# time is not Converting Sqldatetime format in android

Tags: android

```
deliverdate="Wed Dec 23 14:49:02 IST 2015 ";    
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date today = null;
try {
    today = (Date) fmt.parse(deliverdate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

java.sql.Date dt = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
String finaltimedate = dt.toString();
```

i am converting given date to Sqlformat datetime  in android  using given code but i am getting wrong Output finaltimedate : `2015-12-23` while i want  this format `23-12-2015 5:00 PM` please tell me where am doing wrong please suggest me

Comment: Where you want it see?

Comment: If you want this format `"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm a"` why do you pass this one `"E MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy"`? Also, I don't think this date is valid `"Wed Dec 23 14:49:02 IST 2015 "`

Comment: If in the database then just you need to specify datetime output. See [it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm)

Comment: Wed Dec 23 14:49:02 IST 2015  
  i have this date and i want to convert in to 23-12-2015  14:49:02 PM

Comment: @Dhaval Patel   any Solution for this Que?

Comment: @MhanazSyed i have tried everything I could, But I am enable to parse "IST" formatted date to Date object. It looks like "IST" is not supported in android, Though i am not sure about it. Same thing is working well in simple java program.

Comment: cant we make String as Like this 23-12-2015 5:00 PM so that i can pass it in to API?

Comment: @MhanazSyed "Wed Dec 23 14:49:02 IST 2015" are you generating this string or getting it from server?

Comment: what you have taken datetime in database as a 'text' or 'datetime'

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM a");
String finaltimedate = sdf.format(today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using locale

```
 private String convertDate(String date) {
            try {     
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date d = format.parse(date);
                SimpleDateFormat serverFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
                return serverFormat.format(d);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```